# Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After get request, I receive an object and pass it through props to the timer component, then in console “Warning: Received NaN for attribute of child elements. If expected, convert the value to a string. "
On the page a timer first appears in the form NaN: NaN: NaN: NaN, and only then it works fine

```
const Lobby = () => {
  let {id} = useParams()

  const [lobby, setLobby] = React.useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${ENDOPOINT}/list/${id}/`, {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setLobby(data)
      })
  }, [])

return (
    <PageTemplate>
      <div>
         <Timer date={lobby.date}/>
        }
      </div>
    </PageTemplate>
  )
}
```

Timer

```
const Timer = (props) => {
    const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState('00');
    const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState('00');
    const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState('00');
    const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState('00');
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const  countdownDateFormat = `${props.date}`.split("+")[0]
      const countdownDate = new Date(countdownDateFormat).getTime();

      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const distance = countdownDate - now;

      const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
        let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        if(distance < 0) {
          clearInterval(timer)
        } else {
          setTimerDays(days)
          setTimerHours(hours)
          setTimerMinutes(minutes)
          setTimerSeconds(seconds)
        }
      }, 1000);
    }, [timerSeconds]); 

  return (
    <section className='timer'>
      ...
    </section>
  )
}

export default Timer
```

Answer (score 0):

While your fetch didn't set `setLobby` yet, the value in `lobby` is an empty string, because you passed it as initial value to setState. Therefore, when you access `date` property here
`<Timer date={lobby.date}/>`
it's `undefined`

After that you try to manipulate this value, which causes NaNs to appear. You can hide the timer until the `lobby` value is fetched, or set some valid initial value.